# passing data to javascript in webview before android level 17 (4.2.2)

Tags: javascript, android

I am working on some charting library in javascript that call from android.

Understand that JavascriptInterface only available after Android API Level 17 (4.2.2)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html

I want to support android device before 4.2.2

is there anyway to pass a json to javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Understand that JavascriptInterface only available after Android API Level 17 (4.2.2)

`addJavascriptInterface()` has been around since API Level 1. What you are linking to is the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation, which has only been around since API Level 17. Neither of these things have anything to do with your problem.

> is there anyway to pass a json to javascript?

On API Level 19+, use `evaluateJavascript()`. On API Level 18 and below, use `loadUrl("javascript:")`, using the same basic syntax used for bookmarklets on desktop browsers.