# WebView.evaluateJavascript alternative in API <= 18

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have to call a javascript method from my webview, passing parameters from native. And the result I have to get back in native. In api 19+ I'm using

```
mWebView.evaluateJavascript(JAVASCRIPT_NATIVE_REFERENCE_NAME, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {

                    }
                })
```

And its working fine. But `evaluateJavascript` is not supported in API <=18 . Can someone please show a sample how it can be done in API 18 below. I already saw some SO answers

[passing data to javascript in webview before android level 17 (4.2.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033852/passing-data-to-javascript-in-webview-before-android-level-17-4-2-2)

[How to get return value from javascript in webview of android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android)

as shown in second question , can we call any method present in javascript like `view.loadUrl("javascript:alert(functionThatReturnsSomething())");` ??
Where we get the callback in this case. It would be helpful if someone could show a sample. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "can we call any method present in javascript like view.loadUrl("javascript:alert(functionThatReturnsSomething())"); ?" -- so long as you do not need the result, sure. "Where we get the callback in this case" -- you don't. There is no callback. At best, you use `addJavascriptInterface()` to inject some Java object into the JavaScript namespace, then have the function call a method on that object. This has security issues.

Comment: I need the result back in java code , and based on that I have to call the next javascript method. In this case what can I do? Can u share some code?

Comment: "In this case what can I do?" -- I would recommend that you set your `minSdkVersion` to 19 and use `evaluateJavascript()`.

Comment: app has to support from 18 :(